# Android: Reading a file from SD card and display on image view giving error

Tags: android

[image]The simple code is to read the image file from the SD Card and display on image view
Following is the code

```
import java.io.File;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        File imgFile = new  File("/storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/Test.jpg");

        if(imgFile.exists()){

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I am using Samsung S3 as the android device. Error I am receiving is "java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start the activity component" in logcat. The required permission  was also considered.
Need suggestions to make the code work correctly. ( Also app successfully installed in device but unable to run properly).

Comment: show your logcat please

Comment: @cuoka image of logcat is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
```

cannot be done before the `setContentView();`

The way you've done it `myImage` will be null, therefore the `NullPointerException` I suppose you're getting.